# async-series TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: node.js

Getting the error mentioned in the title inside calculateGST line total = req.itemdetail[0].price;

When i try to print the same inside getItemDetail()  getting the correct value. I believe there is something to do with the asynchronous behaviour. how do i make it work like synchronous without using waterfall or any other packages? i want the soltion with the series package.

```
 exports.calculateGstBaseOnInput = function(req, res,next) {
        for(var item of req.body.so_items) {
            req.productid = item.productid;
            req.qty = item.qty;
            series([function(done){
                getItemDetail(req,res);
                done();
                getCartItems(req,res);
                done();
                calculateGST(req,res);
                done();
              }], function(err) {
                //console.log(err) // "another thing"
              })
         }
       // res.json({status : 'gst', statusMessage : 'gst success'});

    }

    getItemDetail =function(req,res)
    {
        var SQL = "mysqlquery";
        mysqlConnect.query(SQL,function(err, result, fields){
                    if(err)
                    {

                        res.json({status : 'Failure', statusMessage : 'item does not exist'});
                    }else if(result.length < 0){
                        res.json({status : 'Failure', statusMessage : 'item does not exist'});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        req.itemdetail = result;
                    }
                });
    }
    getCartItems =function(req,res)
    {

        var SQL="mysqlquery";
        mysqlConnect.query(SQL,function(err, result, fields){
                    if(err)
                    {
                        res.json({status : 'Failure', statusMessage : 'item does not exist'});
                    }else if(result.length < 0){
                        res.json({status : 'Failure', statusMessage : 'item does not exist'});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        req.cartItems = result;
                    }
                });
    } 
    calculateGST =function(req,res)
    {

            total = req.itemdetail[0].price;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to pass `done` `callback` to subsequent `functions` in `async-series` array. I have modified the code, can you check if this one works for you?

```
 exports.calculateGstBaseOnInput = function(req, res, next) {
     for (var item of req.body.so_items) {
         req.productid = item.productid;
         req.qty = item.qty;
         series([function(done) {
                 getItemDetail(req, res, done);
             },
             function(done) {
                 getCartItems(req, res, done);
             },
             function(done) {
                 calculateGST(req, res, done);
             }
         ], function(err) {
             console.log(err) // "another thing"
         })
     }
     // res.json({status : 'gst', statusMessage : 'gst success'});

 }

 getItemDetail = function(req, res, cb) {
     var SQL = "mysqlquery";
     mysqlConnect.query(SQL, function(err, result, fields) {
         if (err) {

             res.json({
                 status: 'Failure',
                 statusMessage: 'item does not exist'
             });
         } else if (result.length < 0) {
             res.json({
                 status: 'Failure',
                 statusMessage: 'item does not exist'
             });
         } else {
             req.itemdetail = result;
             cb();
         }
     });
 }
 getCartItems = function(req, res, cb) {

     var SQL = "mysqlquery";
     mysqlConnect.query(SQL, function(err, result, fields) {
         if (err) {
             res.json({
                 status: 'Failure',
                 statusMessage: 'item does not exist'
             });
         } else if (result.length < 0) {
             res.json({
                 status: 'Failure',
                 statusMessage: 'item does not exist'
             });
         } else {
             req.cartItems = result;
             cb();
         }
     });
 }
 calculateGST = function(req, res, cb) {

     total = req.itemdetail[0].price;

     //After all success operation call the callback
     cb();

 }
```

Comment: this is the output i am getting. inside getItemDetail
inside getItemDetail
inside getCartItems
inside getCartItems
inside calculateGST
inside calculateGST. Output i expect is inside getItemDetail
inside getCartItems
inside calculateGST
inside getItemDetail
inside getCartItems
inside calculateGST

Comment: @ExplainDownVote It's the way nodejs handles async calls, it doesn't wait for network/IO calls to finish, I will suggest collecting the result and processing it after loop ends in final callback handler

Comment: don't understand.